# MQTT-SN Payload size

Tags: udp, mqtt, iot

What is the maximum payload length of MQTT-SN packet over UDP? The UDP does support 65507 bytes of data on its payload, but I wanted know what's the max size of MQTT-SN payload. Also, can the data be compressed in the MQTT-SN payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MQTT-SN protocol spec can be found [here](http://mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf)

Section 5 talks about the message format and section 5.2 talks about how the header is made up.

There is the length field which can be 1 or 3 bytes long followed by the message type byte. Then a number of fields depending on the type of message.

The 3 byte size can represent a max total message of 65535 bytes

Assuming a Publish, then section 5.4.12 has the format for a publish message. Also assuming you are using topic ids rather than full text topics. The header will be 9 bytes in size (assuming you want a large message so 3 byte size needed) this means the max payload can be 65498 bytes. But this is a protocol upper limit, the actual limit will be constrained by the networks MTU.

Comment: Thank you @hardillb, for your insight on that, I did check it out, but some forums said that only 4kB of data can be sent over UDP.

Comment: Having thought about it some more it will depend on the MTU of the network you are using as well